# Out of memory exception while reading large excel sheet in java

Tags: java

I am trying to upload excel sheet of 10000 records and 29 columns but giving me out of memory error, to solve this in increase memory size in eclipe.ini file but no use. I decrease columns upto 4 then it doesn't give me error. but for more columns error is coming . Here with attached screenshot of error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbj7B.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You should give more memory to you application, not to eclipse. Take a look at your run configuration and add -Xmx1024M (or more) to your VM arguments. If memory is still an issue, try using POI event API (https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#XSSF+and+SAX+%28Event+API%29)

Comment: I am putting code where i m getting error while reading excel file

Comment: List<CommonIO> lstEmatrix   = new ArrayList<CommonIO>();
  Properties prop = null;
  prop = ConnectionManager.getPropertiesObj();
  String path = prop.getProperty("Export_File_Path");

  try {

   FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path + "/" + fileName));
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
   XSSFSheet excelSheet = null ;

Comment: while creating new XSSFWorkbook(file) i m getting error

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.createElementXobj(Cur.java:257)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.startElement(Cur.java:2992)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxHandler.startElement(Locale.java:3198)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportStartTag(Piccolo.java:1082)

Comment: As I said you need to give more memory to your java process. If you start your app from eclipse see my response above (here is nice manual http://www.planetofbits.com/eclipse/increase-jvm-heap-size-in-eclipse/). If you are not sure that it worked use -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m as VM arguments and print result of Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() to stdout. That prints how much memory is your jvm using in bytes and result should be roughly 2048m bytes. If you cannot add more memory you cannot use XSSFWorkbook. In this case you will need to use POI event API

Comment: Thanks for reply